# doubt in this complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

if $\gamma$ is the uper semicircle with a small semicircle around origin I have to calculate
$\int_\gamma d z \frac{e^{i z}}{z}$. My professor uses a different method but when he has to calculate the integral around the smaller circle he does in a different way, However I found online that the limit could be moved inside the integral . Why? I thought the integral what is $t$ and the limit was in $\epsilon$ and ou can change the order . Is it right ? Or there is another reason ? I leave here all calculations

\begin{aligned}
& \int_\gamma d z \frac{e^{i z}}{z} \\
& \int_{c_{\varepsilon}} d z \frac{e^{i z}}{z} \\
& C_{\varepsilon}(t)=\varepsilon e^{i(\pi-t)} \\
& \dot{c}_{\varepsilon}(t)=-i \varepsilon e^{i(\pi-t)}=-i c_{\varepsilon}(t) \quad t \in[0, \pi] \\
& \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{c_{\varepsilon}} d z \frac{e^{i z}}{z}\left(-i \int_0^\pi \lim _{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} e^{i \varepsilon e^{i(\bar{\pi}-t)}} d t=-i \int_0^\pi d t=-i \pi\right. \\
&
\end{aligned}